# Rails 4: How to set up associations so that a user has many types of assets?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'd like to set up my application such that a User has many Assets, and the assets table would reference other tables by it's columns "asset_type" and "asset_id".

Each asset type, should have it's own table with it's own columns.

This should allow: user.assets.count to get a count of all asset types

Also: 
user.images to get all the images where id = asset_id (and asset_type = "image").

I've looked at polymorphic associations, multiple table inheritance, has_many :through, etc. I can't seem to get this one figured out.

I tried to upload a diagram, but I do not have enough reputation.

I apologize in advance if this has been asked before, perhaps it's the wording I'm searching or otherwise - but I've been very unsuccessful at finding this solution after several attempts. Any help very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assets
  has_many :images
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true
end

class Image < Asset
  # inherits user, profile and all Asset attributes
end

class ImageProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :asset, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy
end
```

So it's STI for Asset which of course needs a "type" column (string). You can then have all the types you need: Image, Video, Document, ...

And polymorphic association for the profiles of each type. ImageProfile is the table for Image specific columns, and you create other tables for VideoProfile, DocumentProfile, etc.

You can read more about this architecture here http://railscasts.com/episodes/394-sti-and-polymorphic-associations

If ImageProfile has a column exif_data, then you access it via image.profile.exif_data.

To create a new image, you can do this:

```
@image = current_user.images.new.tap do |image|
  image.profile = ImageProfile.new profile_params
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I've reviewed that video twice again, and tried to set this up the way that you've described; however, it seems that user.images returns the asset records, rather than the profile records. Have I missed something obvious for accessing the profiles?

Comment: Yes you have. You are not supposed to access the profile record. You access the image, and when you need to access parameters specific to the profile you access them via the image.

Comment: The thing you probably miss is that the Image has a profile association, because it inherits it from Asset.

Comment: Oddly enough, it seems that the asset record is being returned for `@image.profile` as well.

`@image.profile
 => #<Image id: 1, user_id: 1, profile_id: 1, profile_type: "Image", created_at: "2015-02-22 08:26:37", updated_at: "2015-02-22 08:34:25">`

Comment: Can you copy paste your current code for all relevant classes and methods in a gist ?

Comment: Sure - [gist](https://gist.github.com/codeurge/753b6b2e1b6ff029525f), though it's pretty much exactly what you wrote. Unless I've done something wrong in the migrations.

Comment: You're missing t.string :type to your create asset migration

Comment: Oops - you're right! That helped a lot. One last question, what would you recommend for creating the profile at the same time as the image? As of now the profile_type, profile_id and profile are all nil - only the type is set on creation. If I create the profile, and update the profile_type and profile_id accordingly - everything is working as expected.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a ton for making my first question a success. :)